# how to redirect empty parent category to its first non empty child category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, categories, redirect

In Wordpress, If parent category is empty then it will redirect to its first child category that is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
$category = get_queried_object();
    $count_post = $category->count;

    if($count_post==0)
    {
       $args=array(
                'child_of' => $cat-id,
                'hide_empty' => 1,
                'orderby' => 'id',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'depth' => '1' 

            );
            $categories=get_categories($args);
            $cat_link;
            foreach($categories as $category) {
                  $cat_link=get_category_link( $category->term_id );
                break;
            }
               wp_redirect( $cat_link ); 
    }
```